# how to change a specific value in a dropdown using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I would like to change the text of a specific dropdown after the page loads

```
<select id="qty_" name="qty[]" class="Field45 quantityInput">
<option selected="selected" value="1">1</option>
    <option  value="2">2</option>
    <option  value="3">3</option>
    <option  value="4">4</option>
   etc... until value=45  
</select>
```

how do I go about changing 3 into : 3 (free)
so this :  `<option  value="3">3 (free)</option>`
this needs to be done in jquery
here is what I have so far:

```
        $('document').ready(function(){

        val = $('.Field45').val();

        if (val == '3') {
        $("Field45").val('3 (Buy 2 get 3rd FREE) ');
        }

        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$('.Field45 option[value="3"]').text('3 (free)');
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fCB28/)

Answer (score 0):

First add the `id` tag to the option you want to change, e.g.:

```
<option id="option3" value="3">3</option>
```

Then in the jQuery code add the folowing line:

```
$("#option3").text("3 (free)");
```

Comment: I want to grab it by its value.not id :)